# How to do proper cross compilation for C on Mac?

Tags: c, macos, cross-compiling

I am trying to compile C code on a Mac (M2), with as target windows. I have tried this in the past on linux, with success, but there doesn't seem to be a straightforward way on Mac.

On the linux machine I was able to get a whole range of cross compilers from GNU, they had the system headers built in, so it was really really simple, something like

```
gcc-...-mingw main.c -o main.exe
```

would create a simple windows executable. From there it was as simple as moving the main.exe file to a usb drive or cloud to and transfer it to a windows machine to run it. Really simple!

For Mac I have found some resources about Clang, but you need to provide the system headers yourself, which I have no idea how to do. And there is more setting up, which I don't want to get into if there is a solution as simple as the one I just showed.

My question: What is the  way to compile a C program on a Mac with the target system being windows, or even Linux?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: So all you need is MinGW headers/libraries and a native Clang for Mac. You can get the headers from https://winlibs.com/ or [Quasi-MSYS2](https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/quasi-msys2). Then you just need the right Clang flags, which, I believe, are `--target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --sysroot=path/to/mingw/files -fuse-ld=lld -pthread -stdlib=libstdc++ -femulated-tls -rtlib=libgcc`.

Comment: @JohnAlexINL That thread is about the opposite situation. OP uses Mac as host, not target.

Comment: mb I misread, thank you @HolyBlackCat lol

Answer (score 0):

Visual Stdio Code has support for various [C compilers](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp) native for M2. It isn’t a full IDE, simply a code editor with extensions.

You should be able to download the plugins/extensions you need via the GUI interface and let it manage the environment.